# Maven extract Dependency without creating dependency directory

Tags: maven, maven-dependency-plugin

The configuration below works but I end up with an extra directory that I don't want. So I have `target/webapp/dep-A/<depedency contents>`, what do i need to change to get it to be `target/webapp/<depedency contents>`?

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.8</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>unpack</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>unpack</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>myGroup</groupId>
                                <artifactId>dep-A</artifactId>
                                <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                                <type>zip</type>
                                <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/webapp</outputDirectory>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                        <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: my workaround is to specify `dep-A` version as a property then i can ensure the dependency and the `war` plugin path are in sync.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the `maven-dependency-plugin` `unpack` goal has not a [`postprocess` optional parameter](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/unpack-mojo.html#Optional_Parameters) letting you, for example, chmod-ing or moving files. So I don't think exists an elegant way to do what you want only using the `maven-dependency-plugin`.

In addition to the `maven-dependency-plugin` you might use the `maven-antrun-plugin`, binding it to a subsequent phase which the `maven-dependency-plugin` is binded to, to copy/move/delete your files and directories.

Comment: Yes it seems like this functionality is just not available for this goal. I dislike breaking out of one tool to use another, I try and avoid things like the `maven-antrun-plugin` wherever possible, it is about as good a workaround as the one I commented.